# Receive WebRTC in VLC/FFMPEG or other application

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, vlc, webrtc

We would like to receive WebRTC stream.
The stream is sent from a browser and the receiver can be VLC or FFMPEG or some other application.
Is there a way to achieve this goal? 
If so, how? 
Is there a way to get the raw data?

Thanks,
Ronen

Comment: You can use the [native WebRTC API](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/) or [Licode's MCU source code](https://github.com/ging/licode/tree/master/erizo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server

I won't copy/paste code here - aiortc is a python package you can install through pip, and then you can run the example - it worked out of the box for me.

Big thanks to the author of aiortc.